# show/hide record based on field Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I have table `users`, which contain `users` that can log in into my web, so i have something like this, u can see that `admin` have `privileges` 1 while `qwert` have `privileges` 2, i want to display anything that have `privileges` 2, how can i do something like that?

[image]

in my web it's look something like this, u can see that admin been showed in that table, i don't want admin record to be shown, i just want to display record that have `privileges` 2
[image]

> VIEW

```
@foreach($users as $user) 
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>{{$user->cv_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->cv_position}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->cv_country}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->cn_phone}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->cv_address}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-success" title="edit" data-id={{$user->id}} data-action="user-edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" title="delete" data-id={{$user->id}} data-action="user-delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

> > CONTROLLER

```
public function index(){
    return view('user')
    ->with('title','User')
    ->with('users',User::all());
}

public function getAll(){
    $data = User::all();
    $response = array(
            'content' => $data,
            'status' => 'success',
        );
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

how to do that? certain if else case maybe?

Comment: You should add a where clause to the $users variable, using the query builder. Can you post your controller which contains the $users variable?

Comment: done, check the code again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another **good practice** is using **scope** like this 
**- In User model**

```
public function scopeMember($query){
    return $query->where('privileges','<>',1);
}
```

**- In Controller**. So easily to get only member 
Change

```
->with('users',User::all());
```

To

```
->with('users',User::member()->get());
```

Comment: in controller which part should i add that line of code?

Comment: I updated. I suggest to do this way for future maintainable and more expandable

Comment: wow ok that's work, can u explain it to me briefly because i can't see the connection between function in model and calling the function in controller

Comment: Laravel translates the member() function automatically to the new added scope, with the usual query as its argument. This is just a quick and smart way to add certain where clauses to the usual query.